# Fill matrix with function values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, loops, for-loop, matrix

I've got 3 functions, `oe1(n)`, `oe2(n)` and `oe3(n)`.

I want to create a matrix representing the function values.

The structure of the matrix should be like this:

```
A = [oe1(0) oe2(0) oe3(0); oe1(1) oe2(1) od3(1); ...... ; oe1(N-1), oe2(N-1), oe3(N-1)];
```

I've tried filling it with a `for` loop, but it does not work.

Is there a standard Matlab operation for this? I really can't figure out how to do it.

Anders.

```
oe1(n1) = sin(2*pi*F*n1+phi)
oe2(n1) = ones(length(n1),1);
oe3(n1) = n1*Ts

pol = (oe2)'

vector_x = [a; b; c];
vector_veardier = [oe1(n1), 1, oe3(n1)]
xi = 1:N-1;


for i = 2:N-1;     
   for j = 1:3    
      vector_veardier(i, j) = oe1(j);    
   end    
end
```

Comment: What does not work? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your functions accept vectors? If so you can use:

```
A = [oe1((1:N)'), oe2((1:N)'), oe3((1:N)')];
```

but otherwise you might have to use `arrayfun`:

```
A = [arrayfun(@oe1, (1:N)'), arrayfun(@oe2, (1:N)'), arrayfun(@oe3, (1:N)')];
```

Note that in your provided code you have not defined oeN as functions, but as some kind of array with a value inserted at position n1.

One way to do it with a for loop would however be:

```
A = zeros(N,3);
for i = 1:N,
  A(i,:) = [oe1(i), oe2(i) oe3(i)];
end
```